# dimension reduction of discrete numerical data

Tags: multivariate-analysis, dimensionality-reduction

I have a bivariate discrete numerical dataset and would like to reduce its dimensions to a single variable.  A 9 x 8 table of counts of the (x,y) data values is:

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6 7
   -----------------------
8 | 10 38 58 79 50 19 15 1
7 | 22 61 67 86 43 19  7 0
6 | 44 70 44 44 19  6  2 0
5 | 45 33 29  8  5  2  1 0
4 | 62 15  8  4  1  0  1 0
3 | 12  6  7  2  2  1  0 0
2 |  1  2  1  0  0  0  0 0
1 |  3  0  0  0  0  0  0 0
0 | 10  2  2  0  1  0  0 0
```

Something that seems reasonable is to fit a  curve from (0,0) to (7,8) and project the data onto this [in the study (0,0) is least knowledgeable, (7,8) most knowledgeable].  The reduced variable would be the distance from (0,0) to (7,8) after projection.  Does anyone know how to do this?

The X variable is the sum of number of facts correctly recalled after reviewing some materials.

The Y variable is a sum of correct responses to TRUE/FALSE questions relating to those materials.

Another example of these type of data is the following

```
      0   1   2  3
     -------------
  8 | 5  82 143 37
  7 |21 139 163 23
  6 |23 122  86 15
  5 |17  63  29  6
  4 |21  29   8  1
  3 | 6  13   3  0
  2 | 3   4   2  0
  1 | 2   0   0  0
  0 | 4   0   0  0
```

in this case the X variable has values 0 to 3.

Suggestions for other methods also appreciated.

Comment: From your table the variables are only weakly associated, so that any reduction of the data would lose information without obvious gain. That is apart from the fact that what you propose implies treating the scores as if they were measured; such practice divides people here and in statistical science generally. All that said, the average of two scores seems simpler than what you propose. There is lots of discussion in other threads on how to treat ordinal data.

Comment: @NickCox: not very strongly indeed, but also not *so* weakly (corr. coeff. is 0.45). First PC is almost exactly diagonal and accounts for 72% of the total variance. Of course projecting on the diagonal PC is equivalent (up to a constant factor) to taking the average, as you suggested.

Comment: @amoeba Fair enough, but your PCA presumably treats the ordinal scores as if measured.

Comment: @NickCox: yes, but I am not sure I understand your point. From how I understood the question, the scores *were* measured. Or do you mean that in fact some continuous variables were measured and then rounded? Even if so, why would PCA be not a reasonable approach?

Comment: The relationship between the two variables is I think non-linear - one of the variables is a weaker measurement of knowledge than the first, and also measures some slightly different knowledge.  For the purpose of the study these are to be converted to a single variable.

Comment: The data were described as ordinal and the values are clearly all integers; more than that no one knows except the original poster. Personally I would be quite willing to apply PCA with some cautions; I am just hinting at the widespread attitude to the effect such practice is widely regarded as dubious if not invalid.

Comment: @PaulM You can't have it both ways; if these data are ordinal, nonlinearity is not on the table. If you think that they are in effect rounded measurements, that's your judgment, but it is not obviously implied by your description.

Comment: @PaulM: could you describe how the measurements were done? What do the numbers 0-8 mean? This would help to resolve the issue we are discussing here with Nick Cox.

Comment: @amoeba  I'll do that.  I slightly bungled the question the data are more discrete numerical than ordinal.  I understand now how to edit it and will do so.  Apologies for confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Following the discussion in the comments above and your edits, it is clear that the data is not ordinal, but simply discrete. It makes everything rather easy: e.g. you can run the PCA.

In order to do that, you need to convert your count table into a data matrix with two columns (X and Y) and as many rows as you have observations (1070). I always prefer to look at a scatter plot before doing PCA; in this case scatter plot will be hard to interpret because almost all the points overlap, so a better way to plot it would be with some random jitter:

[image: PCA on discrete data]

Now we see that the data points are obviously spread along the main diagonal. Indeed, PCA tells us that the first PC explains 72% of the total variance, and is pointing in the direction (0.69, 0.72). This is *very* close to the diagonal (0.71, 0.71), so you can as well take the diagonal itself.

Now you only need to project your data onto the first PC (or on the diagonal). Which in case of the diagonal is equivalent to taking the average between X and Y, as @NickCox suggested above. So if I were you, I would center the data (subtract mean X and mean Y) and take the average. But it would be a good idea to mention in the methods that the first PC was almost exactly the diagonal.

**Update**

@PaulM made a very good point in the comments: the square form of the grid might bias the covariance matrix towards the diagonal. Indeed, looking at these data, one might suspect that if the measurement scale (0-8) somehow had a broader range, then some of the points that fall on the boundaries of the square grid would actually be located further away from its centre. Constraining all the data points to the square grid can introduce a bias.

I think it is a valid concern, and I don't know a principled way to deal with it. However, I can suggest an ad-hoc method. Let us cut out chunks of the grid that have a form that is not diagonally elongated. A "cross" seems to be a natural choice: one could take 5 neighbouring grid positions that form a cross, but I decided to take 12 positions that form a larger cross (see figure below). It is easy to select points belonging to such a cross, as they have distance less than 2 to the centre of the cross, and all other grid locations are further away.

On the following picture I show 10 cross positions that I used (black dots), and the red circle shows the boundary for the first cross. [Note that blue points were jittered only for visualization, whereas all the analysis was done on the unjittered points.] For each cross I computed the PCA and plotted the direction of the first PC as a black line.

[image: PCA on a grid]

One can see that all black lines are roughly diagonal, confirming that the bias does not play a big role in the above conclusions.

Still, to try to correct the possible bias, one could take the average over the 10 "bootstrapped" PCs: (0.79, 0.61), which is 7.5 degrees below the diagonal, or maybe the weighted average with number of points in each cross serving as a weight: (0.80, 0.59), which is 8.5 degrees below.

Comment: The problem with PCA as I see it is that part of the rotation is due to the array-like structure of the data.  If PCA is applied to a rectangular array with random counts it will rotate it and if it is applied to an upper triangular array with random counts it will rotate it to the diagonal, that being the rotation to explain most of the variance.

Because of this and since I know that (0,0) and (7,8) are worst/best responses, I was thinking of the non-linear projection.  The data are almost constrained to the upper triangular, but there is more structure to them than random counts.

Comment: That said, perhaps the easiest thing is to view PCA as a linear approximation to this and go with that.

Thanks for all the feedback.

Comment: @PaulM: that is a very good point. In fact, at the moment I would not know how to correct for it; maybe somebody else will come up with a suggestion. However, it's clear that in your case counts are not random and actually do seem to be stretched along the diagonal: there are less counts on the two diagonal lines above the main diagonal, and also less counts in the corner.

Comment: As it turns out, I have a number of these to resolve.  I'll add another example to the above in case of interest.

Comment: @PaulM, I did not get the point of your initial comment. The data you display is actually this: you display a scatterplot of two scale discrete variables. PCA is to draw an optimal "diagonal" line there. What are your doubts about it? Are you confused with that your data are skewed?

Comment: @ttnphns: I think PaulM meant that the square form of the grid might bias the covariance matrix and hence the PCA. Looking at these data, one might think that if the measurement scale (1-8) somehow had a broader range, then some of the points that fall at the boundaries of the square grid would actually be located further away from its centre. Constraining all the data points to the square grid, one can introduce a bias. I think it is a valid concern.

Comment: @PaulM, I updated my reply with some extra analysis, trying to correct for the diagonal bias.

Comment: @ttnphns, I updated my reply with some extra analysis, trying to correct for the diagonal bias.

Comment: That is a very interesting analysis and I'm glad that it agrees with the full PCA.  That said, I wonder if one could construct an example where the conclusions did not agree?  I guess that would be another question.  Thank you.

Comment: @PaulM: It is actually easy to construct such a case. If I take an "upper-left" triangular array of the same size filled with random counts, then the "global" PC points along the diagonal (so your intuition was correct), but my "local" PCs of individual "crosses" all point in the random directions (as should be expected), so their circular average is not really meaningful. BTW, if I fill with random counts the whole array (not only its triangular half), then the leading PC is *not* automatically diagonal.